# What's the equivalent of gcc's -mwindows option for cl in windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, gcc

```
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-mwindows'
```

Seems `-mwindows` is only for `gcc`, does `cl` has a similar option?

Answer (score 4):

That would probably the [/subsystem option to the linker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk%28VS.71%29.aspx)
Specifically /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS

It allows you to choose between compiling a console application and a windows application by setting a flag in the PE header

Comment: It reports: `cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS'`

Comment: @Runner It is documented as a linker option. You probably must tell `cl` to pass the option to the linker.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq ,how do I tell `cl` to do that?

Comment: I googled "cl options" and one of the first hits was http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h(VS.80).aspx , which contains the information. And I have not used cl in years, so I can't really test it.

Comment: To pass linker options on the `cl` command line, put `/link ` before them

Comment: Why are you using `cl` directly and not through visual studio or a makefile created by visual studio?